# Detect if Visualforce Page is rendered as a Mobile Card or as stand-alone page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Is there any way to detect if a visualforce page is rendered inside a Salesforce1 Mobile Card as opposed to being rendered as a stand-alone page?  I'm aware of a few javascript/URL Parameter workarounds to detect if the page is being rendered in S1 but haven't figured out any way to determine where in the S1 app a page is being rendered.

Since there's no way to override the behavior of the `<article>` container around the mobile card, certain workflows require either poor page layout or a sub-optimal user experience to navigate from a mobile card to some other page.